# Puppeteer fails to load SPA website on lambda but not local

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I have been working on building a webscraper with puppeteer. The Website I scrape is this: https://siemens.cateringportal.io/menu/Erlangen%20S%20GS1/Mittagessen

It is probably written with Angular and dynamically builds its content. Therefore, web scraping only works using a headless browser (either selenium or puppeteer).

I already wrote a script with works fine locally on my machine.
[(local script of puppeteer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mmUy.png)
Since the site needs longer to build, I addedd page.waitForSelector("app-product-list") which waits for the site to build until the specific HTML entitiy is present.

The next step was to implement the script in AWS lambda [(puppeteer code in lambda)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Yp0.png). Puppeteer itself works fine in AWS lamdba. However, the website I want to scrape never builds completeley. Therefore the scripts exits with a timeout error
[(error message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYGoE.png)

The script itself is implemented using puppeteer-core and sparticuz-chromium. Both plugins are added as a AWS layer. Puppeteer in lambda works for other websites, but not for this one.

In short: Puppeteer can load this specific website locally but fails when used in AWS lambda.

At AWS lambda, I have tried following mitigations:

- Use a different version of nodejs (both 14 and 16 fail)
- Use more memory (4gb) and increase the timeout (3mins) -> still fails
- Use a different location for the lambda function (frankfurt and ireland) -> still fails
- Add the code in the lambda layer -> also fails
- Use a different chromium version: I used chrome-aws-lambda with puppeteer 10.1 and it also fails

Beside AWS lambda, I have tried to build a Docker image with the script. However, the script has the same issue of the timeout when running in Docker.

Comment: In Firefox under Ubuntu I get "ERROR FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)."  Can you see a browser log?

Answer (score 0):

When looking at that website using a browser `app-product-list` part gets loaded, however doing the same via code on systems where the default language is English it doesn't load: [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jbTK.jpg), it only appears when `Mittagessen` is replaced with `Lunch` *(or Side dishes, Vegetable bar, Salad bar for the other menus)*,

local & docker code : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txUPx.jpg)

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {

async function loadPage(menu){ 
    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(`https://siemens.cateringportal.io/menu/Erlangen%20S%20GS1/${menu}`,{ waitUntil: 'load', timeout:0});

    let names = null;
    try {
        let selector = 'app-product-list div.name-column > span';
        await page.waitForSelector(selector,{ timeout: 5000 }); // timeout in 5 secs
        names = await page.$$eval(selector, el => el.map(x => x.textContent.replace(/\n/g, ",").trim())); // get contents, cleanup a bit
    } catch {
        console.log('menu items not found');
    }

    await browser.close();
    return names;

}

console.log({
    english : await loadPage('Lunch'),
    german : await loadPage('Mittagessen')
});

})().catch(err => console.error(err)). finally(() => browser ?. close());
```

AWS Lambda :

- just selected `Runtime:Node.js 18.x` in *Runtime settings*, set `Memory: 512 MB` and `Timeout : 1 minute` in *General configuration*
- uploaded code as zip file to Amazon S3 got, the S3 URI, placed that link into the code section of the lambda function, and pressed test

package.json file :

```js
...
"dependencies": {
    "@sparticuz/chromium": "112.0.2",
    "puppeteer-core": "19.8.1"
}
```

code : [result on AWS Lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTM40.jpg)

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium");

exports.handler = async (event) => {

async function loadPage(menu) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args : chromium.args,
        defaultViewport : chromium.defaultViewport,
        executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
        headless: chromium.headless,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(`https://siemens.cateringportal.io/menu/Erlangen%20S%20GS1/${menu}`, { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0 });

    let names = null;
    try {
        let selector = 'app-product-list div.name-column > span';
        await page.waitForSelector(selector, { timeout: 5000 }); // timeout in 5 secs
        names = await page.$$eval(selector, el => el.map(x => x.textContent.replace(/\n/g, ",").trim())); // get contents, cleanup a bit
    } catch {
        console.log('menu items not found');
    }

    await browser.close();
    return names;

}

let result = {
    english : await loadPage('Lunch'),
    german : await loadPage('Mittagessen')
};

return result;

};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your investigation. The link was indeed the issue. The links only work on the correct website language selected, which seems to be set automatically.